# Does strong error reduction for PostQMA exist?

Tags: complexity-theory, qma, postselection

$\mathsf{PostQMA}$ can be defined as the following (see [Morimae-Nishimura](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.01514.pdf) and [Usher-Hoban-Browne](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.08118.pdf)):

> A promise problem $\mathcal{L}=(\mathcal{L_{yes},L_{no}})$ is in $\mathsf{PostQMA(c,s)}$ if there exists a polynomially bounded function $m:\mathbb{Z}^+\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and a polynomial time quantum verifier $V$, which is a polynomial time uniformly generated family of quantum circuits $\{V_{x}\}_{x\in\{0,1\}^n}$ on $n+m$ qubits such that for every input $x$ and $(\langle \psi|\otimes\langle0|^{\otimes m}) V_x^{\dagger} (|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes I_{n+m-1}) V_x(|\psi\rangle\otimes |0\rangle^{\otimes m}) > 2^{-p(n)}$ for some polynomial $p$:
>
> - Completeness: if $x \in \mathcal{L}_{yes}$, there exists a witness $|\psi\rangle$ such that $$\frac{(\langle \psi|\otimes\langle0|^{\otimes m}) V_x^{\dagger} (|00\rangle\langle00|\otimes I_{n+m-2}) V_x(|\psi\rangle\otimes |0\rangle^{\otimes m})}{(\langle \psi|\otimes\langle0|^{\otimes m}) V_x^{\dagger} (|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes I_{n+m-1}) V_x(|\psi\rangle\otimes |0\rangle^{\otimes m})} \geq c.$$
> - Soundness: if $x \in \mathcal{L}_{no}$, for any witness $|\psi'\rangle$ such that $$\frac{(\langle \psi|\otimes\langle0|^{\otimes m}) V_x^{\dagger} (|00\rangle\langle00|\otimes I_{n+m-2}) V_x(|\psi\rangle\otimes |0\rangle^{\otimes m})}{(\langle \psi|\otimes\langle0|^{\otimes m}) V_x^{\dagger} (|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes I_{n+m-1}) V_x(|\psi\rangle\otimes |0\rangle^{\otimes m})} \leq s.$$

Namely, we do the postselection such that if the first output qubit is $0$, then we consider the second output qubit. Usually, $\mathsf{PostQMA}:=\mathsf{PostQMA(2/3,1/3)}$. As mentioned in Morimae-Nishimura, the error bound can be amplified from $(2/3,1/3)$ to $(1-2^{-r(n)},2^{-r(n)})$ for any polynomial $r$.

---

The naive approach is requiring **polynomially many copies** of the witness and using the standard Chernoff bound on indicators which indicate whether $x \in \mathcal{L}_{yes}$ or $\mathcal{L}_{no}$ and repeat such trials. As mentioned in [Aaronson's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0412187.pdf) on $\mathsf{PostBQP}$.

---

A little-advanced approach is requiring **two copies** of the witness. Using the proposition 2.9 in [Kuperberg's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.0512.pdf), the $\mathsf{PostBQP}$ verifier $\mathcal{V}$ can be thought as two quantum polynomial-time algorithms run by Alice and Bob that report "yes" with probabikity $a$ and $b$ respectively. For some constant $c>1$, postselection guarantee the *free-to-retry* property: 
- $\mathcal{V}$ reports "yes" if $a > cb$; 
- $\mathcal{V}$ reports "no" if $a < cb$.

And Alice and Bob are free to retry if $(a,b)$ is not in either above ranges. Hence, we can do something similar to the [Marriott-Watrous gap amplification](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0506068) (or [the phase estimation variant](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.1549)), consider the following projections: 
$$\begin{aligned}
\Pi_0 &= I_n\otimes |0\rangle\langle 0|^{\otimes m},\\
\Pi_1^A &= V_x^{\dagger} (|00\rangle\langle 00|\otimes I_{n+m-2}) V_x,\\
\Pi_1^B &= V_x^{\dagger} (|01\rangle\langle 01|\otimes I_{n+m-2}) V_x.\\
\end{aligned}$$
Invoking Marriott-Watrous procedure for $\Pi_0\Pi_1^A\Pi_0$ and $\Pi_0\Pi_1^B\Pi_0$ and using the free-to-retry property, then we can do the same thing with the standard Chernoff bound.

---

Therefore, the final question is that could we do the promise gap amplification using **only one copy** of the witness (i.e. strong error reduction) for $\mathsf{PostQMA}$?

Historically, such strong error reduction usually will have complexity-theoretic consequences, such as showing that $\mathsf{QMA}\subseteq \mathsf{PP}$ or $\mathsf{PreciseQMA}\subseteq \mathsf{PSPACE}$ (see [space-efficient strong error reduction](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.08192)). So such strong error reduction for $\mathsf{PostQMA}$ might give us a *direct proof* for $\mathsf{PostQMA}\subseteq\mathsf{PSPACE}$.

Two facts might be helpful:

- [Morimae-Nishimura](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.01514.pdf) proved that $\mathsf{PostQMA}=\mathsf{PreciseQMA}$ where $\mathsf{PreciseQMA}$ is a $\mathsf{QMA}$-type class with exponentially small completeness-soundness gap. And $\mathsf{PreciseQMA}$ have such strong error reduction (but it needs exponential time) -- so even such strong error reduction for $\mathsf{PostQMA}$ exists, it might need exponential time to amplify.
- [Aaronson](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0412187) proved that $\mathsf{PostBQP}$ machine can do efficiently generated uniformly polynomial-size bounded-error quantum circuits, where the circuits can consist of arbitrary $1$- and $2$-qubit **invertible** linear transformations. It is not clear to me whether such Marriott-Watrous type error reduction exists for *invertible* gates complexity class or not.